# MariaDB Galera journalctl

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mariadb, galera

I've noticed something weird.

I have 3 nodes galera cluster, installed using mariadb.
I'm pretty sure that I did all three nodes installations exactly the same.

All three nodes display their --version `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.13-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2`

But 1 one out of the 3 nodes, the one that bootstrap with `galera_new_cluster` command to start the cluster. The `journalctl -u mariadb` has no entry, while all the logs are at `journalctl -u mysql` instead. The other 2 nodes are logged to `journalctl -u mariadb`, which is expected.

How is this possible?

Also, This same node that differs seems to fail from time to time.

Comment: Looks as if you are running into the problem described here?

https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-17961

Comment: so you saying there is no issue here, because of the alias?

Comment: I think that on the bootstrap node "systemctl start mysql" was used originally instead of "systemctl start mariadb", while the mariadb service was not enabled yet.

When the service has not been enabled yet the "mysql" alias does not exist, but there's still the old mysql SysV init script, to which systemd falls back in that case ...

Comment: hmm.. if the bootstrap node does use `systemctl start mysql` initially. then that make sense.